# How to concatenate a string in PHP?

Tags: php

I'm doing a string concatenation:

```
$url = "http://www.majesticseo.com/reports/site-explorer/summary/"
       + $page['page_url'] + "&IndexDataSource=F"
       ;
```

and this is what I get when I print it:

```
0
```

where does the 0 come from?

Comment: *You* are funny (not the PHP array): Using `+` to concatenate strings makes PHP laugh about you and shows a nice 0 instead (a sign of perfection). Even it is possible to use `+` in some other languages to concatenate strings, in PHP you need to use `.`, otherwise PHP will convert the strings into integers and sum them. http://php.net/operators

Comment: yeah, I am too used to dot.net and java.. too bad php is the only language that used . instead of +

Comment: Well, PHP is not strictly typed, so I guess it needs this difference in the syntax so that you can specify the outcome.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It comes from the fact that you're performing an arithmetic operation on non-numeric data. Use the concatenation operator (`.`) instead.

Comment: lol..I am too used to dot.net..sorry for the stupid question