# Consolidate 4 strings in 1 single string

Tags: php

I'm still trying to make my own Credit Card checker to check if the credit card is valid or not.

I have 4 inputs, wich needs 4 numbers in eachs.

```
<input class="inputCard" type="text" style="width: 50px;" name="ccNumber1" id="ccNumber1" required/> - 
<input class="inputCard" type="text" style="width: 50px;" name="ccNumber2" id="ccNumber2" required/> - 
<input class="inputCard" type="text" style="width: 50px;" name="ccNumber3" id="ccNumber3" required/> - 
<input class="inputCard" type="text" style="width: 50px;" name="ccNumber4" id="ccNumber4" required/>
```

Each inputs requires 4 numbers. For my script to check the numbers, I need to consolidate the 16 numbers in one.

Example:

After the user has enter the 16 numbers in the 4 inputs i would get something like this :

```
$ccNumber1 = 1234;
$ccNumber2 = 1234;
$ccNumber3 = 1234;
$ccNumber4 = 1234;
```

Now what I need is to have -> $ccNumber1, $ccNumber2, $ccNumber3, $ccNumber4 into one string.

```
$NewVar = $ccNumber1 + $ccNumber2 + $ccNumber3 + $ccNumber4;
```

Since $ccNumber1 = 1234, $ccNumber2 = 1234, $ccNumber3 = 1234 and $ccNumber4 = 1234, $NewVar should be : `1234123412341234

However I can't do $ccNumber1 + $ccNumber2 + $ccNumber3 + $ccNumber4.
That doesn't works..

How should I do ?
Thanks for reading and I appreciate all you help !`

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php

Comment: use . instead of + because php is dynamic typing so if you use + and number is converted as number so it will sum in one number

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to concatenate a string in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10966893/how-to-concatenate-a-string-in-php)

Comment: You are not concatenating properly for PHP do like `$ccNumber1.$ccNumber2..`. The `.` is concat operator not `+`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`+` is not string concatenation in PHP, it is numeric addition.  You need to use a `.` instead:

```
$NewVar = $ccNumber1 . $ccNumber2 . $ccNumber3 . $ccNumber4;
```

However I would propose using this as the input name for all the number inputs to create an array:

```
name="ccNumber[]"
```

And then just:

```
$NewVar = implode('', $_POST['ccNumber']);
```

Comment: Ok, but i have 4 inputs, so I would have 4 arrays right ?

Comment: 4 inputs with the name `ccNumber[]` then the `$_POST['ccNumber']` array will contain 4 items.

Comment: Thank you so much !
I'm still learning php, and I would like to know more some other developers, do you mind giving me your skype or email adresse so I could contact you in the futur is I ever need you again (and I think I will aha) ?